# AlertDialog is not getting shown

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

This is the code that I have written to display the Alert Dialog, still it is not shown

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("GPS not Enabled");
                builder.setMessage("Please enable the GPS for proper functioning of the app");
                builder.setNeutralButton("Go To Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                });
                builder.setCancelable(false);

                AlertDialog showDialog = builder.create();
                showDialog.show();
```

Please help. I am really unable to understand the reason.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

The alert dialogue code is okay. If you're talking about the response after the alert dialogue appears. Then change neutral to positive. Look at the code that I have posted.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button alertButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        alertButton = findViewById(R.id.alertBtn);

        alertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setAlertButton();

            }
        });
    }

    public void setAlertButton(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Fire alert ")
                .setPositiveButton("Fire", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        
        AlertDialog showDialog = builder.create();
        showDialog.show();

    }

}
```